# Dart - "This function has a return type of 'FutureOr<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>', but doesn't end with a return statement."

Tags: flutter, dart

How should I correct this warning? I need to show an alert dialogue after 10 seconds

```
Future<Map> myMethod(myAPIUrl, headers) async {
  await http.get(myAPIUrl, headers: headers).then((response) {
  //my code
  });
}

myMethod('myapi.com')
            .timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: (){
            print('time timeout')
            })
            .then((response) {
        //mycode
        });
```

Thx you!

Comment: `timeout` is not a static method.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I don't understand your comment.

Comment: `Future.timeout` is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

The callback in the `timeout` function of `Future` expects a value of the same type as your original `Future` to be returned. This is so that the `Future` returned by callback always has a result, whether it times out or not.

Simply return an object of the same type that your original future would in the callback of `timeout`.

```dart
myMethod('myapi.com')
  .timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: (){
    print('time timeout');
    //show dialog code here
    return Map();
  })
  .then((response) {//Response will end up being an empty map on timeout and the return of `myMethod` otherwise
    //mycode
  });
```